# didReceiveRemoteNotification is not called in inactive mode when tapping the app icon

Tags: ios, notifications

Tapping the app icon does not call didReceiveRemoteNotification when tapping the app icon and the app is in inactive. However, the payload can be handled in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions by tapping the notification.

It works when the app is in background or foreground.

Is there a way to handle remote notifications by tapping the app icon in inactive?

Precondition:
 1. Remote notification is set.
 2. "content-available":1 is set in the payload.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following function:

`- application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:`

Comment: so,, notfication is coming when your app in the background or inactive. you can see the badge number on the app icon. you clicked the app icon, then you could get the userinfo right?

Comment: I can't get user info from didReceiveRemoteNotification by tapping the app icon when the app is inactive (killed). I can get it from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions by tapping the notification.